# What's wrong with this YesodAuth instance?

Tags: haskell, yesod

I've just migrated from current yesod scaffold to latest `yesod-1.6.0`, `yesod-auth-1.6.2`.

```
instance YesodAuth App where
    type AuthId App = UserId

    -- ....

    authenticate creds = runDB $ do
        x <- getBy $ UniqueUser $ credsIdent creds
        case x of
            Just (Entity uid _) -> return $ Authenticated uid
            Nothing -> return $ UserError InvalidUsernamePass
```

Before migration this code worked well. But after the following error occurs.

```
.../src/Foundation.hs:212:26: error:
    • Could not deduce: m ~ HandlerFor site8
      from the context: (MonadHandler m, HandlerSite m ~ App)
        bound by the type signature for:
                   authenticate :: forall (m :: * -> *).
                                   (MonadHandler m, HandlerSite m ~ App) =>
                                   Creds App -> m (AuthenticationResult App)
        at src/Foundation.hs:212:5-16
      ‘m’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          authenticate :: forall (m :: * -> *).
                          (MonadHandler m, HandlerSite m ~ App) =>
                          Creds App -> m (AuthenticationResult App)
        at src/Foundation.hs:212:5-16
      Expected type: m (AuthenticationResult App)
        Actual type: HandlerFor site8 (AuthenticationResult App)
    • In the expression:
        runDB
          $ do x <- getBy $ UniqueUser $ credsIdent creds
               case x of
                 Just (Entity uid _) -> return $ Authenticated uid
                 Nothing -> return $ UserError InvalidUsernamePass
      In an equation for ‘authenticate’:
          authenticate creds
            = runDB
                $ do x <- getBy $ UniqueUser $ credsIdent creds
                     case x of
                       Just (Entity uid _) -> return $ Authenticated uid
                       Nothing -> return $ UserError InvalidUsernamePass
      In the instance declaration for ‘YesodAuth App’
    • Relevant bindings include
        authenticate :: Creds App -> m (AuthenticationResult App)
          (bound at src/Foundation.hs:212:5)
    |
212 |     authenticate creds = runDB $ do
    |                          ^^^^^^^^^^...
```

I don't know why it can't pass type check. `runDB` works well in places not related to `yesod-auth`.

**EDIT:** I extracted codes that seems relevant.

```
class (MonadResource m, MonadLogger m) => MonadHandler m where
    type HandlerSite m
    type SubHandlerSite m
    liftHandler :: HandlerFor (HandlerSite m) a -> m a
    liftSubHandler :: SubHandlerFor (SubHandlerSite m) (HandlerSite m) a -> m a

instance MonadHandler (HandlerFor site) where
    type HandlerSite (HandlerFor site) = site
    type SubHandlerSite (HandlerFor site) = site
    liftHandler = id
    {-# INLINE liftHandler #-}
    liftSubHandler (SubHandlerFor f) = HandlerFor f
    {-# INLINE liftSubHandler #-}

newtype HandlerFor site a = HandlerFor
    { unHandlerFor :: HandlerData site site -> IO a
    }
    deriving Functor

instance MonadHandler (HandlerFor site) where
    type HandlerSite (HandlerFor site) = site
    type SubHandlerSite (HandlerFor site) = site
    liftHandler = id
    {-# INLINE liftHandler #-}
    liftSubHandler (SubHandlerFor f) = HandlerFor f
    {-# INLINE liftSubHandler #-}
```

With above definitions, I wonder the reason that the following cannot pass type check.

```
problem :: (MonadHandler m, HandlerSite m ~ App) => m ()
problem = (undefined :: HandlerFor App ())

    • Could not deduce: m ~ HandlerFor App
      from the context: (MonadHandler m, HandlerSite m ~ App)
        bound by the type signature for:
                   problem :: forall (m :: * -> *).
                          (MonadHandler m, HandlerSite m ~ App) =>
                          m ()
        at /intero/intero1940cny-TEMP.hs:210:1-52
      ‘m’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          problem :: forall (m :: * -> *).
                 (MonadHandler m, HandlerSite m ~ App) =>
                 m ()
        at /intero/intero1940cny-TEMP.hs:210:1-52
      Expected type: m ()
        Actual type: HandlerFor App ()
    • In the expression: (undefined :: HandlerFor App ())
      In an equation for ‘problem’: problem = (undefined :: HandlerFor App ())
    • Relevant bindings include
        problem :: m ()
          (bound at /intero/intero1940cny-TEMP.hs:211:1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put `liftHandler .` before every `runDB`.